# Text column in array

Tags: tables, amsmath, arrays

I am trying to do something that seems relatively simple but I can't get it to work. Basically, I would like one of the columns in my math mode array to be text, so I am trying to use pre and post processing `>{}` and `<{}` like so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \begin{array}{{>{\text\bgroup}c<{\egroup}}@{:}c@{=}c}
    a & x^2 & x^2 \\
    b & y^2 & y^2 \\
    c & z^2 &  z^2
    \end{array}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

This leads to an "illegal character in array arg" error. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're close. In the modified example below, I'm using the `array` environment and define a special column type, `L`', that's automatically in text mode. The reason this works is because `l`, `c`, and `r` are automatically in math mode in an `array` environment.

Note the second intercolumn specifier, `@{{}={}}`: The pairs of `{}` curly braces before and after the `=` sign are there to inform TeX that the `=` sign is to be treated as a so-called `mathrel` object. In case this sounds a bit cryptic: `mathord`, `mathbin`, and `mathrel` objects each have different amounts of whitespace before and after them. An easy way to make TeX treat a `=` symbol as a `mathrel` object even though it occurs in a non-equation setting is to pre- and post-fix it with (empty) math "atoms", viz., `{}`.

Note also that it's not necessary to use the `align` environment as there is really only one "equation" in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{L}{>$l<$}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{L@{\quad}c@{{}={}}c}
       some text:            & x^2 & x^2 \\
       more thoughts:        & y^2 & y^2 \\
       really deep thoughts: & z^2 & z^2
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't believe I was including the `array` package and depending on LaTeX's native array support. So for the line `\newcolumntype{L}{>$l<$}` to work, I guess I will have to use the `array` package and understand the syntax.

Comment: Okay, so that was pretty amazing. I was wondering why you were telling me all the stuff about `mathrel` till I added the math atoms and noticed the difference. Double thumbs up to you. ;)

Comment: @FgNu: The syntax isn't that difficult to master, trust me. Given that the `l`-type column is automatically in math mode when in an `array` environment, the `>$` prefix serves to *end* math mode; conversely, the `<$` specifier serves to re-enter math mode at the end of the cell's content. As long as you load the `array` package, you don't actually have to use the `\newcolumntype` command to set up a column of type `L`; it suffices (but is less readable, I'd say) to specify `>$l<$`.